# Query for last occurance of priceId in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a `Stripe` product with two prices (annual and monthly recurring) and want to query from firebase, but only getting one `priceId` back (last created)!!!

```
firebase.db.collection('plans').where('active', '==', true).get().then(snapshot => {
  const products = {};

  snapshot.forEach(async productDoc => {
   products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
   const priceSnap = await productDoc.ref.collection("prices").get();
   // console.log('priceSnap', priceSnap)
   priceSnap.forEach(priceDoc => {
     products[productDoc.id].prices = {
       priceId: priceDoc.id,
       priceData: priceDoc.data()
     }
   })
 })
 setProducts(products)
 console.log('products', products)
})
```

[firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PsWH.png)
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tebms.png)

Comment: I think you're having an issue with asynchronous code but can't tell for sure due to the code formatting - it's hard to read. Can you please format your code for readability?

Comment: It appears this `setProducts(products)` is being called after the asynchronous firebase closure so `products` may or may not populate quickly enough so operation will be intermittent. Firebase data is only valid within the closure, not after.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with managing the data you are fetching, A query snapshotcontaining an array of docs that you are iterating through without changing the `productDoc.id` ensures you are overwriting existing entries with the next document.

```js
priceSnap.forEach(priceDoc => {
     products[productDoc.id].prices = {
       priceId: priceDoc.id,
       priceData: priceDoc.data()
     }
   })
```

if your prices were re-arranged into an array of which you can manage your data better with array find and filter methods.

For example:

```js
priceSnap.forEach(priceDoc => {
     products[productDoc.id].prices.push({
       priceId: priceDoc.id,
       priceData: priceDoc.data()
     })
   })
...
products[productDoc.id].prices.find(item => item.priceData.period == "monthly")
```

Comment: If my interpretation of your database is incorrect, would you update your question with some examples of your database and its intended structure?

Comment: example wasn't working....anyway I solved the problem by making two products instead of one with two prices. thx